# What is the purpose of keeping "allow background activity" and "allow background data usage" in the game?

Tags: pokemon-go, android

Does anyone know what the purpose of having mobile data used in the background/allow background activity on Android is for?

Why should I keep them on for Pokemon Go?

Comment: Probably it has to do with the Adventure sync?

Comment: I see, background activity would make sense but I don't know about what background data usage would have to do with that.

Comment: Background data usage probably pings the server every minute or so for notifications like raid invites. (and that does cost data)

Comment: I see, thank you! So that's how you would get notifications from the app I'm guessing, and if you turn it off while on mobile data it won't.

Answer (score -1):

"Allow Background Activity" - is for the Pokemon Go to keep running if it is not being actively displayed on the screen. This mode is called background. Otherwise, it might be suspended or closed by operating system (Android).

"Allow Background Data Usage" - is to allow Pokemon Go running in background to still use data connection. This is so that game running in background can still communicate with the servers to report the progress.